# editing existing excel workbook using xlrd, xlwt and xlutils

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, xlwt, xlutils

How to edit and save the data in an existing excel workbook using xlrd, xlwt and xlutils module?
could someone please provide a sample code to edit and save the data in excel workbook?

I am trying to put data from one workbook to another.

```
import xlrd, xlwt, xlutils

wb1 = xlrd.open_workbook('workbook1.xls', formatting_info=True)
wb2 = xlrd.open_workbook('workbook2.xls', formatting_info=True)

value 1 == wb2.sheet_by_name('Sheet1).cell(2,1).value

wb1.sheet_by_name('Sheet1').cell(2,2).value == value1
```

How to save this data in workbook1.xls?

Sorry, I asked this before, but I am trying to be more clear about my question this time.

Thank you very much.

Comment: There are some syntax errors in your code, you can fix them by using the [edit] link.

Comment: Do you mean you want to edit an Excel workbook "in place"?

Comment: yes, editing and saving the existing workbook.

Comment: Not sure there's a way to do that, but you could always use the Python Excel libraries to read the workbook, do your manipulations, and then write it to the same file. See http://www.python-excel.org/

Comment: read the tutorial that you can access via www.python-excel.org

Answer (score 1):

You can save with `wb1.save('workbook1.xls')`. You might get an IOError that the file already exists. In that case try to `os.remove()` the file before saving.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the previous answer of using the xlwt library save method. But you should also do some proof reading of your code. You are missing a closing quote for Sheet1 and variable names cannot have spaces.